# Instantiate predefined number of object along a raycast in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

I have a raycast that's being rendered every frame based on 2 points, and those 2 points change position each frame.

What I need is a system that doesn't need a direction, or a number of objects, but instead takes in 2 points, and then instantiates or destroys as many objects as necessary to get the instantiated objects from one side to another minus `spaceBetweenPoints`. If you wanted you could think of it as an [Angry Birds Style slingshot HUD](https://angrybirds.fandom.com/wiki/Slingshot?file=Sling.PNG), except without gravity, and based on raycasts.

**My Script:**

```
    public int numOfPoints; // The number of points that are generated (This would need to chnage based one the distance in the end)
    public float spaceBetweenPoints; // The spacing between the generated points
    private GameObject[] predictionPoints; // The prefab to be gernerated
    private Vector2 firstPathStart; // The starting point for the raycast (Changes each frame)
    private Vector2 firstPathEnd; // The ending point for the raycast (Changes each frame)
    
    void start()
    {
         predictionPoints = new GameObject[numOfPoints];
         for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++)
         {
              predictionPoints[i] = Instantiate(predictionPointPrefab, firePoint.position, 
              Quaternion.identity);
         }
    }

    void Update
    {
         Debug.DrawLine(firstPathStart, firstPathEnd, UnityEngine.Color.black);
         DrawPredictionDisplay();
    }

    void DrawPredictionDisplay()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++)
        {
            predictionPoints[i].transform.position = predictionPointPosition(i * spaceBetweenPoints);
        }
    }

    Vector2 predictionPointPosition(float time)
    {
        Vector2 position = (Vector2)firstPathStart + direction.normalized * 10f * time;
        return position;
    }
```

The current system simply takes in a starting position, a direction, and then moves a preset number of objects in that direction based on time. This way of doing it also causes problems because it's endess instead of only going till the end of the raycast: (Pardon my drawing skills)

[image: Exampel Image]

```
Blue line = raycast
Black dots = instantiated prefab
Orange dot = raycast orange
Green dot = end of raycast
```

**Notes:**

- `direction` is the momentum which I set in the editor, I needed it to put together what I currently have working, but it shouldn't be necessary when running based on points.

Comment: Can you please tell me what, **1.** is this is 3D or 2D. **2.** How do i know the position of ```StartPoint``` and ```EndPoint```?

Comment: @Ankit Sure, as questions tag says, it's 2D. The position of for the starting and ending of  the raycast is determined by the variables `firstPathStart` and `firstPathEnd` which I change based upon other less related parameters every frame. Any other questions I may answer?

Comment: That's good enough, I'll take two dummy object to represent Start and End position

Comment: I made a script which gives your Vector3 positions for all the points in a List and after that you can Run a loop and Instenciate All the objects that you want, would that be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask me I would say it is kinda easy if you know little bit of Math trickery. I'm not saying that I'm very good at Math, but once you get it it's kind of easy to pull off next time. Here if I try to explain everything, i won't be able to explain clearly. Take a look as the code below I've commented the whole code so that you can understand easily.

Basically I used a Method called `Vector2.Lerp()` Liner Interpolation, which means that this method will return value between `point1, and point2` based on the value of 3rd argument `t` which goes from `0 to 1`.

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform StartPoint;
    public Transform EndPoint;
    public float spaceBetweenPoints;

    [Space]
    public Vector2 startPosition;
    public Vector2 endPosition;

    [Space]
    public List<Vector3> points;

    private float distance;

    private void Update()
    {
        startPosition = StartPoint.position; //Setting Starting point and Ending point.
        endPosition = EndPoint.position;
    
        //Finding the distance between point
        distance = Vector2.Distance(startPosition, endPosition);

        //Generating the points
        GeneratePointsObjects();

        Debug.DrawLine(StartPoint.position, EndPoint.position, Color.black);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        //Drawing the Dummy Gizmo Sphere to see the points
        Gizmos.color = Color.black;
        foreach (Vector3 p in points)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(p, spaceBetweenPoints / 2);
        }
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        //Validating that the space between two objects is not 0 because that would be Raise an exception "Devide by Zero"
        if (spaceBetweenPoints <= 0)
        {
            spaceBetweenPoints = 0.01f;
        }
    }

    private void GeneratePointsObjects()
    {
        //Vlearing the list so that we don't iterate over old points
        points.Clear();

        float numbersOfPoints = distance / spaceBetweenPoints; //Finding numbers of objects to be spawned by dividing "distance" by "spaceBetweenPoints"
        float increnment = 1 / numbersOfPoints; //finding the increment for Lerp this will always be between 0 to 1, because Lerp() takes value between 0 to 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < numbersOfPoints; i ++)
        {
            Vector3 v = Vector2.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, increnment * i); //Find next position using Vector2.Lerp()
            points.Add(v);//Add the newlly found position in List so that we can spwan the Object at that position.
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** *Added, How to set prefab on the positions*

I just simply Destroyed old objects and Instantiated new Objects. But remember instantiating and Destroying object frequently in your game in unity will eat-up  memory on your player's machine. Os I would suggest you to use Object-Pooling. For the reference I'll add a link to tutorial.

```
private void Update()
{
    startPosition = StartPoint.position; //Setting Starting point and Ending point.
    endPosition = EndPoint.position;

    //Finding the distance between point
    distance = Vector2.Distance(startPosition, endPosition);

    //Generating the points
    GeneratePointsObjects();

    //Update: Generating points/dots on all to location;
    InstenciatePrefabsOnPositions();

    Debug.DrawLine(StartPoint.position, EndPoint.position, Color.black);
}

private void InstenciatePrefabsOnPositions()
{
    //Remove all old prefabs/objects/points
    for (int i = 0; i < pointParent.childCount; i++)
    {
        Destroy(pointParent.GetChild(i).gameObject);
    }

    //Instantiate new Object on the positions calculated in GeneratePointsObjects()
    foreach (Vector3 v in points)
    {
        Transform t = Instantiate(pointPrefab);
        t.SetParent(pointParent);
        t.localScale = Vector3.one;
        t.position = v;
        t.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps please see below links for more reference

[OBJECT POOLING in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA)

[Vector2.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html)

Comment: Only one little flaw: How can a `numbersOfPoints` be a `float`? ;)

Comment: @derHugo you are right. It should be integer rather then float. But as long as we are not dealing with a <1 increment value in control variable it's fine. But that need to be changed. I'll do that by tomorrow morning. Good night

Comment: Your script works really well with 2 exceptions we'll need to work out. **1.** How can I replace `OnDrawGizmos()` with a gameobject prefab? I need the player to be able to see the dots a gizmos won't cut it. **2.** `spaceBetweenPoints` doesn't act like the spacing between the points but rather the size to the gizmos and thus how many gizmos there are. If I set `spaceBetweenPoints` to 0.5 I get a bunch of tiny gizmos placed back to back, and if I set it to 2, I get 3 large gizmos all placed back to back.

Comment: Let me edit my script to your needs, and ```spaceBetweenPoints``` is working as it should when it comes to position, and I just put the same value as the radios of the sphere. so that if the space is smaller nothing looks chunky.

Comment: @derHugo I've tried to changing ```numbersObPoints``` to ```int``` and I had to typecast it again to float while dividing with ```1``` in just next statement so i decided to keep it ```float```

Comment: @Ankit `InstenciatePrefabsOnPositions()` references a variable called `pointParent` but at no point is it declared.

Comment: @JhonPiper it is just an empty object where I set all of the object/points to it's children, so that I can destroy once I don't need them that's it. Just create an empty object and assign ```pointParent``` nothing too complicated

Comment: @JhonPiper did you got what you were looking for?

Comment: @Ankit It took a while to implement your code into mine but your code works well. I've gone ahead and marked you answer as correct. However if you would be kind enough to help me with one last thing I would be even more grateful: With setup in particular I have some normal raycasts, aswell as special raycasts (Like this: https://pastebin.com/HDHGv7g5) that limit the physical distance a raycast can travel. But that distance limited combined with your code (https://pastebin.com/TSGi9Nh1) creates a "flickering" problem (https://imgur.com/a/PDQIrkk). It only happens when the line moves...

Comment: causing me to believe it's because in the amount of time the limiter has taken to limit the raycast when moving, a new dot gets drawn and then when the raycast distance goes back to `maxRaycastDistance` there is no longer enough space and the dot gets cleared, but I'm unsure. If you would be so kind, could you test my raycast limiter and look at the issue yourself?

Comment: @Ankit Just make it `1f / numberOfPoints` ;)

Comment: @derHugo I did not thought of that.

Comment: @JhonPiper go to the loop which is is generating all the numbers ```for (int i = 1; i < numbersOfPoints; i++)``` this one. and change the condition from ```i < numbersOfPoints;``` to ```i < numbersOfPoints + 1```. It will add one object in the list of the objects/points

Comment: And one more thing don't forget to take a look at all the reference links that I've posted in my answer.

Comment: @Ankit Adding a `+1` to the `i < numbersOfPoints;` condition has no apparent affect. I've already looked into how Vector2.Lerp works. I intend to look more into object pooling but I don't think it will fix this bug, so I'd like to fix the current issue first before I begin work on improving the efficiency.

Comment: Correction, I applied the `+1` in the wrong spot. There is now there a dot which stays there the whole time, and one that "flickers" on top of it. But my dots are partially transparent so while it could be considered an improvement, it's a workaround, not a fix.

Comment: It is because the way ```Lerp()``` works in Unity. don't remove the ```+1``` and change the ```Vector2.Lerp()``` to ```Vector2.LerpUnclamped()```. That should fix the bug.

Comment: Doing that causes the added dot to appear past the line, but the last dot still "flickers".

Comment: Ok, the flickering object is happening is that  as the length of the line increases or decreases it add or remove the point. I was only able to find a work around which is to useing ```Vector2.Lerp()``` with the condition with ```+1```.  So that the last object will always be at the end of the line and it'll appear to be a completed line.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, your last comment never showed up in my inbox. So the best we've got for now if a workaround? I was hoping to be able to make the dots partially transparent.

Comment: You can just tinker with the loop condition. and you'll be able to find the perfect fit.

Comment: What do you mean by tinker with the condition? Change the `+1` to `+2` and so forth?

Comment: Yes, something similar to that. but you can also change ```int i = 1``` to ```int i = 0```. try doing that as well

Comment: Setting `int i = 0` creates errors, and setting it to anything higher than 1 just subtracts from the total number of dots. Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right.

First, compute the A to B line, so B minus A.
To get the number of needed objects, divide the line magnitude by the objects' spacing. You could also add the diameter of the prediction point object to avoid overlapping.
Then to get each object position, write (almost) the same for loop.

Here's what I came up with, didn't tested it, let me know if it helps!

```
public class CustomLineRenderer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float SpaceBetweenPoints;
    public GameObject PredictionPointPrefab;
    
    // remove transforms if you need to
    public Transform start;
    public Transform end;

    private List<GameObject> _predictionPoints;
    
    // these are your raycast start & end point, make them public or whatever
    private Vector2 _firstPathStart;
    private Vector2 _firstPathEnd;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _firstPathStart = start.position;
        _firstPathEnd = end.position;
        _predictionPoints = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _firstPathStart = start.position;
        _firstPathEnd = end.position;
        
        // using any small value to clamp everything and avoid division by zero
        if (SpaceBetweenPoints < 0.001f) SpaceBetweenPoints = 0.001f;

        var line = _firstPathEnd - _firstPathStart;
        var objectsNumber = Mathf.FloorToInt(line.magnitude / SpaceBetweenPoints);
        var direction = line.normalized;

        // Update the collection so that the line isn't too short
        for (var i = _predictionPoints.Count; i <= objectsNumber; ++i)
            _predictionPoints.Add(Instantiate(PredictionPointPrefab));

        for (var i = 0; i < objectsNumber; ++i)
        {
            _predictionPoints[i].SetActive(true);
            _predictionPoints[i].transform.position = _firstPathStart + direction * (SpaceBetweenPoints * i);
        }

        // You could destroy objects, but it's better to add them to the pool since you'll use them quite often
        for (var i = objectsNumber; i < _predictionPoints.Count; ++i)
            _predictionPoints[i].SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've got the right idea, and your script appear to be relatively close. However, no matter what you do the distance appears to be based on `spaceBetweenPoints`, which means when you set `spaceBetweenPoints` to something small like 0.5f, you get a short line going in the same direction as the raycast, but while it starts at the raycast, instead of removing the proper number of dots, it just puts them relly close together and doesn't reach the end of the raycast. While if you use a higher number like 10, the direction is still correct, and the dots are spread out 10f, but

Comment: once again, instead of removing the proper number of dots, the dots go far beyond the length of the raycast. But if you could fix your current code so that it removes the proper number of dots instead of just letting them go out until we run out of dots. Your script may work.

Comment: Again, I hope I understood you correctly.

 Here, I just display or hide points given a set of a fixed length (your array of GameObjects).
 That way you won't have a lot of Instantiate & Destroy since it's quite heavy on memory usage.

 If you want to create more object on the fly to fill the line, it's really, really similar : just use a List of Gameobject.
 Before running the for loop, update your collection if it's too small.
Look at my code snippet, I updated it.

Comment: I'm fine with disabling the dots, if it becomes an issue I can fix that later. I think you understand what I'm trying todo for the most part, one issue I do have though is that your updated code relies on Transforms while the start and end points of my Raycasts use Vector2's. Your new code also creates a ton of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range` errors on runtime.

Comment: I use two private fields that are Vector2's, transforms are just here to test the script if you need to. Remove them and set your Raycasts points, it's absolutly the same.
I probably did a division by 0, look at the updated snippet.

Comment: I've managed to fix the index errors and replaced the transforms with my Vector2s. But your new updated snippet now generates the dots what appears to be infinitely, no matter what `spaceBetweenPoints` is.